# java timer, how to implement timertask

Tags: java, timer

I want to update object properties every certain time (calling a rest service).

I have the object definition and a class with the new and set

```
public class Obj {
    private String data;
    //Getters and setters
}

//A class with the new and sets:

Public class setData{
     public setData{
        Obj o = new Obj();
        o.setdata("hello");
     }
     TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
     Timer timer = new Timer(true);
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10*1000);
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
/*
       Here is the question. How can I update the data property of        my object?
       I need to call the rest service, and update. The data              string is on a 
       swing UI.
       */
    }
}
```

Here is the question. How can I update the data property of my object?
I need to call the rest service, and update. The data string is on a swing UI.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Well, since you're wanting to update a Swing UI, you should probably consider using a `SwingWorker` - it would allow you to: 1. Call the web service out of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread; 2. Publish the results of the call to the EDT sadly and; 3. Use `Thread.sleep` instead of `Timer`, which is probably much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update components from within a `TimerTask`, your task has to have references to those components. One way to achieve this is to add a constructor to your task to initialize it with the objects you want to manipulate.

For a generic example:

```
public class MyComponent {
    private int data;
    // getters / setters
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final MyComponent myComponent;
    public MyTimerTask(MyComponent myComponent) {
        super();
        this.myComponent = myComponent;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // here you can access your component's data value
        int val = this.myComponent.getData();
        // do whatever you need to
    }
}
```